# monit emits "Skipping 'allow localhost' -- host resolved to [::ffff:127.0.0.1] which is present in ACL already"

Tags: monit

Upon using monit the warning message always shows up. We don't want to get this warning every time we use monit. What could be the reason for this warning message ?

Answer (score 0):

check your monitrc configuration.
In "set http" you added "allow 127.0.0.1" and "allow localhost".
Some of the allowed addresses added twice.
Lutz

p.s.
You should use addresses in the list only (IMHO), hostnames are allowed but a hostname depends to the DNS service.